# Xcode Button Width

Tags: ios, xcode

I have 3 buttons on my project side by side. I added constraints to make them all the same size but when I launch the simulator the middle button becomes less wide than the others I want all 3 to be the same. I tried to control from the middle button to the others and selecting equal width but then they overlap.

Answer (score 0):

Give the second and third buttons a width constraint setting their width equal to that of the first button. At the same time, make sure there is a constraint from the first button to the second and from the second button to the third guaranteeing that they won't overlap.